# I want to display multiple vtkUnstructuredGrids in paraview

Tags: vtk

I've just started to learn VTK to get .vtu format files. I am doing WriteVTU which is one example of [VTK](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/). 
I modified the code slightly so that two tetrahedrons are displayed in ParaView, but only one tetrahedron is displayed in ParaView.

Obviously I'm missing something, but I can't figure where. I'd be grateful for any hints.

This is the code.

```
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkTetra.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader.h>
#include <vtkDataSetMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.h>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkVertexGlyphFilter.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Parse command line arguments
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Required arguments: OutputFilename" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::string filename = argv[1];

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  points->InsertNextPoint(0, 0, 0);
  points->InsertNextPoint(1, 0, 0);
  points->InsertNextPoint(1, 1, 0);
  points->InsertNextPoint(0, 1, 1);

  points->InsertNextPoint(-1, 0, 0);
  points->InsertNextPoint(-1, -1, 0);
  points->InsertNextPoint(0, -1, -1);

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra> tetra =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra>::New();

  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 0);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 1);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 2);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(3, 3);

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra> tetra2 =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra>::New();

  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 0);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 4);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 5);
  tetra->GetPointIds()->SetId(3, 6);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> cellArray =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
  cellArray->InsertNextCell(tetra);
  cellArray->InsertNextCell(tetra2);

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> unstructuredGrid =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
  unstructuredGrid->SetPoints(points);
  unstructuredGrid->SetCells(VTK_TETRA, cellArray);

  // Write file
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  writer->SetInput(unstructuredGrid);
#else
  writer->SetInputData(unstructuredGrid);
#endif
  writer->Write();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the .vtu file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="7"                    NumberOfCells="2"                   >
      <PointData>
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="1.4142135624"         offset="0"                   />
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="56"                  />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="108"                 />
        <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="152"                 />
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
  <AppendedData encoding="base64">
   _AQAAAACAAABUAAAAGAAAAA==eJxjYEAGDfaobGz8hv1IYvux8QElFQn3AQAAAACAAABAAAAAFAAAAA==eJxjYIAAFijNCqXZGIgDAAMAABA=AQAAAACAAAAQAAAADgAAAA==eJxjYYAADigNAACQAA0=AQAAAACAAAACAAAACgAAAA==eJzj4gIAACAAFQ==
  </AppendedData>
</VTKFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. It's just a typo.

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra> tetra2 =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTetra>::New();

  tetra2->GetPointIds()->SetId(0, 0);
  tetra2->GetPointIds()->SetId(1, 4);
  tetra2->GetPointIds()->SetId(2, 5);
  tetra2->GetPointIds()->SetId(3, 6);
```